# putting multiple requirements in composer.json

Tags: php, json, composer-php

I am trying to install `phpmailer`, and have copy-pasted their info in the `composer.json file`. That file already has the following:

```
{   "require" : {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"   } }
```

How do I add all the stuff `phpmailer` needs me to add to `composer.json` without causing an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to avoid having to deal with editing JSON would be to use the command line entirely:

```
composer require "facebook/php-sdk-v4:4.0.*"
composer require ...more stuff...
```

Answer (score 1):

As a comma separated list of elements inside the same set of curly braces:

```
{
    "name": "stuff/stuff",
    "require": {
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*",
        "stuff/stuff": "*",
        "morestuff": "~4.8"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "your name",
            "email": "email@domain.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the question mentions "composer.json file".